# pandas retaining index column when using usecols

Tags: python, pandas

**This is a re-worded version of my question which hopefully makes more sense:**

When using `read_csv` with an implicit index (i.e. the first column in the file does not have a header), everything works and I get a dataframe whose index is the first column in the file - the implicit index column.

However, if I specify `usecols` as an argument to `read_csv`, the implicit index column is ignored and the returned dataframe has a standard index created by pandas (0, 1, 2, 3 etc).

I cannot explicitly pass the index column in the list for `usecols` and then specify the `index_col` argument because the implicit index column has no header (this is how pandas knows it is an implicit index)!

Is there any way around this?

**Here is the original question:**

I am trying to read a csv file which has a column of row indexes which is not named, the rest of the columns are named:

```
       |head1|head2|
index1 | data1 | data2 |
```

When I read in a certain number of columns with usecols, I also want to include the row indexes. However, as these are not named, I can't include the string in my list for usecols.

I've tried doing a combination of an integer index and strings (e.g. `usecols = [0, 'header1', 'header2']` but this does not seem to work.
If I simply specify `ind_col` as 0, it will use the first column in my selection as the index column.

So, how can I read in a name column selection (via usecols) whilst retaining the first, nameless, column in the file as my row index?

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this same issue and was able to solve it using pandas default unnamed method.

```
data = pd.read_csv('advertising.csv', header=0, index_col=[0] , usecols=['Unnamed: 0', 'radio','sales'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try without using usecols, there is [a known bug which means this won't work with a separator other than `,`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2733).

You can read these directly:

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='\s*\|\s*', index_col=[0])
Out[11]: 
        head1  head2  Unnamed: 3
index1  data1  data2         NaN

In [12]: pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='\s*\|\s*', index_col=[0]).dropna(axis=1)
Out[12]: 
        head1  head2
index1  data1  data2
```

*Note: I've had to use `\s*|\s*` as the sep rather than just `|` so as not to include spaces.*

Comment: This isn't a problem with seperators, but with the index column not having a header. Say I just wanted to import the column 'head2', but retain the index column as the index to my resulting series. I can do: pd.read_csv('foo.csv', usecols = [0, 2], index_col[0]), but if I only know the column headers (and not the position), I cannot do: pd.read_csv('foo.csv', usecols = [0, 'head2'], index_col[0])

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this question correctly, I think you may have to read in the entire csv file as a dataframe and then select the columns that you want.... Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(yourdata, index_col=0).loc[:,'header1']
```