# Pandas read csv "usecols=" wont allow filtering by string and index at same time

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to include the index column in a dataframe pandas reads from a .csv file, but when filtering with *"usecols="* I am getting the following error message if I try to include the index column with the data:

> 'usecols' must either be list-like of all strings, all unicode, all
> integers or a callable.

Here is my .csv file data, and though the column has a name "Date" it is unable to see it since it's in the 3rd row:

[image: csv file]

and this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', index_col=0, nrows=0) 
use_col = [col_name for col_name in list(df.columns) if col_name.startswith('M6A=F')] #filters columns
dti = [0]
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=dti+use_col)
```

CAVEAT: I dont want to read the entire csv file into a dataframe, as this in a function being parsed to json via FastAPI and gets really slow that way, so needs to be filtered before reading the csv file, hence *"usecols="* has to be used.

What I have tried so far:
I looked at this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72683185/9594269) but I think that works because its using integers in both cases, while mine is mixing integer and string, unless I have misunderstood the error.

I also tried pandas concat method reading the csv into two dataframes, once to get the index column and then the data, but couldnt seem to get them to join in a way that the index lined up with the data, and it felt like I was creating additional room for error in the output.

There is a [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231830/9594269) which I will try if I cannot get a better solution, but it feels like a dubious method and the OP was posted 8 years ago.

Comment: First column should be index, so `df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=use_col)` should working.

Comment: @jezrael, if I do that then it sets "M6A=F" as the index column in the df (it's the first column returned by ```use_col``` filter) and the rest are ```M6A=F.1, M6A=F.2``` etc...

Comment: I understand, what about `df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=df.columns[:1].tolist()+use_col)` ?

Comment: @jezrael lol, almost, but weirdly it ignores the first column A (Date) but picks up what is actually there in B column, which is another stock ticker (I removed all of them for clarity in my above csv snapshot)

Comment: Hard testing without data, is possibe share file with first 5 rows by dropbox, gdocs... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working callable by function:

```
f = lambda x: 'M6A=F' in x or 'Unnamed: 0' in x
df = pd.read_csv('hist1day.csv', usecols=f, index_col=[0], skiprows=[2])
print(df)
                         M6A=F             M6A=F.1             M6A=F.2  \
NaN                       Open                High                 Low   
2009-03-20  0.6830999851226807  0.6830999851226807  0.6830999851226807   
2009-03-23  0.6995000243186951  0.6995000243186951  0.6995000243186951   
2009-03-24  0.6998000144958496  0.7056999802589417  0.6912999749183655   
2009-03-25  0.6941999793052673  0.7014999985694885  0.6894999742507935   
                       ...                 ...                 ...   
2022-08-04  0.6949999928474426   0.699400007724762  0.6938999891281128   
2022-08-05  0.6972000002861023  0.6978999972343445  0.6873999834060669   
2022-08-08  0.6899999976158142  0.7013000249862671  0.6899999976158142   
2022-08-09  0.6987000107765198  0.6998000144958496  0.6956999897956848   
2022-08-10  0.7081999778747559  0.7091000080108643  0.7080000042915344   

                       M6A=F.3             M6A=F.4 M6A=F.5  
NaN                      Close           Adj Close  Volume  
2009-03-20  0.6830999851226807  0.6830999851226807     0.0  
2009-03-23  0.6995000243186951  0.6995000243186951   392.0  
2009-03-24  0.6963000297546387  0.6963000297546387   588.0  
2009-03-25  0.6901999711990356  0.6901999711990356   616.0  
                       ...                 ...     ...  
2022-08-04  0.6985999941825867  0.6985999941825867  6604.0  
2022-08-05   0.691100001335144   0.691100001335144  9935.0  
2022-08-08  0.6984000205993652  0.6984000205993652  8102.0  
2022-08-09   0.695900022983551   0.695900022983551  8102.0  
2022-08-10  0.7085000276565552  0.7085000276565552   305.0  

[3373 rows x 6 columns]
```